# ASP.NET Checkbox Control CSS using Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

ASP.NET Checkbox control css using Bootstrap and I have lot of checkbox and I dont want checkbox list to apply css. Below is my bootstrap requirement. When I will click any checkbox then It should be check.

[image]

Comment: I am trying this example but not getting asp.net control: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/checkboxradio-css-only

Comment: This is a much better solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56956537/629697

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap in asp. all you need to do is to include bootstrap into your project and when you change the class property of the checkbox that you don't wanted to apply the css.

eg:    `class="color-chkbox"`

Comment: Did you check my this link: bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/checkboxradio-css-only

Comment: you can't use bootstrap css on asp.net control directly.

Comment: @Developer I do all the time. For a asp:dropdownlist, like this CssClass="form-control"