# boostrap 4 custom checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox, bootstrap-4

i have an asp.net bootstrap 4 custom check box which i cannot align in the form group row as pictured Issue with check box

[image]

The form group row code is as follows.

```
<div class="form-group row">

    <asp:Label ID="lblHowDidYouHear" CssClass="col-2 col-form-label" AssociatedControlID="ddlHowDidYouHear" runat="server" Text="How Did You Hear:"></asp:Label>
    <div class="col-4">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHowDidYouHear" runat="server" CssClass="custom-select"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <%--ISSUE WITH THE FOLLOWING--%>
    <asp:Label ID="lblNoDetails" CssClass="col-2 col-form-label" runat="server" Text="Personal Information:"></asp:Label>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="customCheck" runat="server" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Not Provided</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

For context, i have several of these form-group rows (as pictured above) with the same setup within a bootstrap card.

I have googled the hell out of this issue and played with the css in Chrome with no luck.

Has someone come across this issue before and could propose a solution please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Nuevo" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for='<%: Checkbox1.ClientID %>'>Visible</label>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#' + '<%: VisibleChk.ClientID %>').addClass("custom-control-input");

    });</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note, this is an English-language-only site! Edit your question to use English, or it will be flagged for removal.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using the standard `asp:RadioButtonList` etc. If you add it to your `.master` then this becomes a one shot job and will automatically pick up the asp: elements and style them for you:

When placing your control you just need to define

```
CssClass="custom-form-style"
```

for lists and separate items. If you want to use the switch style on checkboxes, you will need to use

```
CssClass="custom-form-style-switch"
```

The script adds all the wrappers and classes for you. One other thing to note is that you must define the labels. You do not need to add the labels as separate elements though. To define a label you need to use

```
Text="FooBar"
```

in the control.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdGender" runat="server" CssClass="custom-form-style">
   <asp:ListItem Value="M" Text="Male" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="F" Text="Female"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbGender" runat="server" CssClass="custom-form-style">
   <asp:ListItem Value="M" Text="Male" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="F" Text="Female"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="FooBar" CssClass="custom-form-style" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="FooBar" CssClass="custom-form-style-switch" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="FooBar" CssClass="custom-form-style" />
```

By default elements placed in the same parent div will be displayed vertically. You will have to play around with it if you want a horizontal layout.

The scripts that look after the formatting are in a function. This has been done so that the styling can be called if you are building elements on the fly, without a page reload.

To call the function use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   BootStrapChecksRadios()
</script>
```

Here is the page load script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      BootStrapChecksRadios()
   });

   function BootStrapChecksRadios() {
      $('input', '.custom-form-style').each(function () {
         if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'custom-form-style')
         {
            $(this).unwrap();
         }
         $(this).addClass("custom-control-input " + $(this).attr('id'))
         $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").addClass("custom-control-label " + $(this).attr('id'))
         if ($(this).attr('type') == 'radio') {
            $("." + $(this).attr('id')).wrapAll("<div class='custom-control custom-radio' />");
         } else {
            $("." + $(this).attr('id')).wrapAll("<div class='custom-control custom-checkbox' />");
         }
      });
      $('input[type=checkbox]', '.custom-form-style-switch').each(function () {
         if ($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'custom-form-style-switch')
         {
            $(this).unwrap();
         }
         $(this).addClass("custom-control-input " + $(this).attr('id'))
         $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").addClass("custom-control-label " + $(this).attr('id'))
         $("." + $(this).attr('id')).wrapAll("<div class='custom-control custom-switch' />");
      });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Superb answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snipppet. The problem is that you have a html `label` and `span` element with the `col` css class. Not sure if that works correctly but I think not.
And the `custom-control custom-checkbox` div is not inside a `div` with a `col` class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
        <asp:Label ID="lblHowDidYouHear" AssociatedControlID="ddlHowDidYouHear" runat="server" Text="How Did You Hear:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHowDidYouHear" runat="server" CssClass="custom-select"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 col-form-label">
        <asp:Label ID="lblNoDetails" runat="server" Text="Personal Information:"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="customCheck" runat="server" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Not Provided</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this does align the check box better. However, the check box can not be clicked now. I will do some googling to see why.

Comment: Yep, your code worked thanks! the issue with the checkbox not clicking was elsewhere! Thank you!

Comment: Using this solution would be tricky to manage if you have `UpdatePanel` doing stuff on server changed.